# Bash terminal does not find an existing file

Tags: bash, pycharm, anaconda

I run `find -name libcublas.so.9.0` to find `libcublas.so.9.0` file which exists under `/usr/local/cuda/lib64/` and `anaconda3/`. This command does not show me the `libcublas.so.9.0` under /usr/local/cuda/lib64 ?? $PATH contains `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` . I think for that reason pycharm does not also find this file even I sepecify  these variables in pycharm settings:

```
PATH    /usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH    /usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export CUDADIR  /usr/local/cuda
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: `man find`: `find ... [starting-point...] [expression]` and `If no starting-point is
 specified, '.' is assumed.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment variables have nothing to do with the find command and its internal working. Probably your command contains some mistake.  The right syntax for what I understand  from your post would be :

```
find / -name 'libcublas.so.9.0' 2>/dev/null
```

or even better if you have **sudo** access :

```
sudo find / -name 'libcublas.so.9.0' 2>/dev/null
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, It seems a pycharm problem!!

Comment: More likely it's that the original search wasn't looking in the right place. By default, `find` searches only under the current working directory. `find /` (as in this answer) will search everywhere you have permissions to, so that should work.